# Google Maps API Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps

у меня есть вопрос: как построить по набору координат (широта и долгота) пройденный маршрут? Подскажите какие либы можно использовать.
P.S. я попробовал либу "Google-Directions-Android" и не нашел там способа отрисовать маршрут. (мб я просто что-то упускаю)

Comment: Посмотрите карту OpenStreetMap. У них есть библиотека для андроид и там есть возможность построение маршрута. Найдете примеры на офф сайте либы

Comment: Делаете запрос на Google-Directions парсите ответ, и наносите Полилайн на карту. Читайте документацию, там все предельно ясно написано.